# Continuously monitor a variable without infinite loop, then do something when it changes

Tags: c#, variables, events, timer, monitoring

I'm not quite sure how to expand my question, but how do you continuously monitor a variable (without an infinite loop/in-UI timer), then do something when it changes? I'm thinking about using an event but I'm not very good at it yet. I'm thinking about System.Threading.Timer but an alternative would be nice.

I'm using .NET 4.0, and will make a Windows Form.

**EDIT**: You can modify the variable, either from input or programatically. It can be any variable: integer, string, boolean, etc.

Comment: Is it a variable that you can change in some way, or code not under your control ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is the variable, what does it do and what uses it etc?

Comment: "Variable" as actual variable or you are talking about field or property?

Comment: Actual variable. like `int foo;` or `string bar;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more simple solution:

Well, it actually isn't monitoring your variable but it tells you when it has been changed.

```
 private string variable = "";//don't acces this variable: it's just for storing the value in it
 string Variable //this variable should be used by all your code
 {
     get { return variable; }
     set
     {
         if (value != variable)
         {
              //the variable has been changed
              //here is usually an event that is raised, but you could also write your code directly here for some simple cases

         }
         variable = value;
     }
}
```

When you want to get or set a new value, take `Variable` -> don't assign anything to `variable`

Comment: Guess I still have to use a timer. This only simplifies it.

Comment: Maybe there could still be a better solution. Why do you exactly want to monitor the variable all the time? I thought it could be enough when you get notified when it changes...

Comment: So it notifies me? that's exactly what I want.

Comment: "notifies you" is a bit too much. But you can execute code when it has been changed :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use INotifyPropertyChanged in order to be notified whenever the variable is changed.

See more : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged ` is WPF artifact, he is talking about `Windows.Forms`

Comment: @Tigran INotifyPropertyChanged isn't a WPF artefact, if it was it wouldn't predate it.